# building android source on mac os xlion

Tags: android, android-source

I just bought a new macbook. I tried to build enviornment for android source code on mac os x lion. Android website suggests to download Xcode 3.1.4 but when i tried to install macports it showed me some error and asked to install Xcode 4.something. I have OSX lion installed. I tried to  instal xcode from app store but now the problem is that xcode path is all messed up. i tried some solutions from google but could get a way around.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: -bash: xcode: command not found and my path is /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/bkaushik/bin

Comment: why don't you install the latest version of Xcode from App Store?